# Changing hosts file through script on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, script, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that editing local `hosts` file.
But it fails because access is denied.

Is there any option to run editing commands as administrator(without `runas` command), from the script it self?

It tried to do "self elevating script" solution, but it fails when it comes to `hosts` edit.

I call PowerShell script with another batch script, if it helps.

Comment: And without right clicking, just run the script and everything will be automatically.

Comment: In a batch using runas would be a pretty normal solution. Why are you limited to not using runas?

Comment: You can create a shortcut to a powershell script and check "run as administrator" in the shortcut properties.  You still have to say "yes" to the UAC prompt, but there's no right-click.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`runas` command in `cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html), use [PowerShell's `Start-Process` cmdlet using `-verb runas`](http://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html), e.g. as follows:

```
Powershell Start-Process PowerShell -verb runas -ArgumentList '"your_PS-script.ps1"'
```

I have tested it with additional arguments

- `'-ExecutionPolicy Bypass'` as my effective execution policy is `Restricted` for `LocalMachine` scope;
- `'-noexit'` to see results in *Powershell* window.

from `cmd` window as follows:

```
Powershell Start-Process PowerShell -verb runas -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass', '-noexit', '"d:\PS_scripts\SE991958.ps1"'
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. It worked as expected.
But can I do the same solution from the ps script it self?
I am calling this script with some flags/params, so I don't need admin for every condition in the script

Comment: For example I am using Add-Content to edit hosts file in IF condition.
So can I give admin permissions only for this IF?

Comment: @igor please do not expand current question scope. Instead, ask another question on a particular problem at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) rather than here including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, consider [accepting my answer](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1770/should-i-accept-this-answer)